# Failed to register Prometheus Gauge to Flink

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus

I am trying to expose a Prometheus Gauge in a Flink app:

```
@transient def metricGroup: MetricGroup = getRuntimeContext.getMetricGroup
    .addGroup("site", site)
    .addGroup("sink", counterBaseName)
@transient var failedCounter: Counter = _


def expose(metricName: String, gaugeValue: Int, context: SinkFunction.Context[_]): Unit = {

    try {
         metricGroup.addGroup("hostname", metricName).gauge[Int, ScalaGauge[Int]]("test", ScalaGauge[Int](() => gaugeValue))
       }
    } catch {
      case _: Throwable => failedCounter.inc()
    }
  }
```

The app runs locally just fine and expose the metrics without any problem.

While trying to move to production I encounter the following exception in Flink task manager:

`WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl - Error while registering metric. java.lang.NullPointerException`

Not sure, what am I missing here.

Why does the local app expose metrics while on the cluster it fails to register gauge?

I use Prometheus in order to expose other metrics from Flink, for example, failedCounter (in the code) which is a counter.

This is the first time I exposed gauge in Flink so I bet something in my implementation is broken.

Please help.

Comment: It would be probably easier to track the error if You could paste the whole stack trace instead of just the Exception.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the problem, but not sure how to solve it. 
```Name collision: Group already contains a Metric with the name 'rejected_by_server'. Metric will not be reported.[10.199.193.172, taskmanager, 0536b010099d06a2693dcad8833ab060, rtbRejectedCounter, Sink: PrometheusSink, 0, site, null, sink, PrometheusSink, hostname, was-prd-web60]```

How can I run get or create gauge and get or create metric? 
The interesting thing is why locals worked with no errors.

Comment: The exception does not match your code; the code has no reference to 'rejected_by_server'. Is 'gaugeValue' guaranteed to be non-null?

Comment: Correct, I change the gauge name from rejected_by_server to test, other than that the code is the same. The value cannot bu Null (can be 0). 
I think I should work with MetricRegistry somehow, but I have not found examples so far.

Comment: How often are you calling expose()? (You are only supposed to register a metric _exactly_ once per subtask.)

Comment: Each time and I understand this is the problem. The question is how can I set an existing gauge value (by metrics) or how can I get existing gauge with metrics object? I didn't find a way to do it using Scala. in Python it's very easy.

Comment: It should suffice to just change 'gaugeValue' (store it in a field, mutate as required). If that doesn't work, then you need some container (akin to an AtomicReference), on which you set the value, with the gauge returning the contained value (i.e., calling some getter on it). Or a method in your UDF that returns the current value, which you then call in your gauge.

Comment: The gauge has many different possible metrics and each metric has it's own value. For example, the gauge test can have 10 different hostnames each one has a value. I think the main challenge I am facing is how to access gauge with a specific metric group. How can I retrieve scalaGauge object with metric group hostname: "localhost"?

Comment: You can't retrieve metrics again. However, there is nothing preventing you from storing the ScalaGauge in a field, and do whatever with it. Note that it is rather unusual to have 1 gauge work as multiple metrics (and it likely will not work as expected with most reporters), so maybe consider registering separate gauges instead, and keep them in a Map as reference.

Comment: Do you know how can I specify labels for a given metric?

Comment: Metrics groups serve the purpose of attaching meta data to metrics. In your example, all metrics registered should have a label "sink" -> counterBaseName.